url()->previous() creating a closed loop
I have a url()->previous() in Laravel, but I’m facing an issue with the back navigation. For example, I’m on the page home/service and then navigate to home/service/main. On the main page, there’s a goBack button that takes me back to service. However, there’s also a goBack button on service that takes me back to main, creating a closed loop. What can I do to avoid this loop?

Hard-code the links instead.

Is hard-coding the URL's in every 'go-back' button an option for you, @MartinYordanov? Also, Welcome to StackOverflow!

To avoid a closed loop with url()->previous() try any of the following:
Cache last page of view in session: Only the session should be updated on a page change. Your controller should
if (session('last_page') != url()->current()) {
   session(['last_page' => url()->previous()]);
}

Then, in your view:
<a href="{{ session('last_page', route('default.route') ) }}">Go Back</a>

Hard code Go Back Route. If always want to go back to particular page, for instance home/service, hard code it: Go Back
